# DllNotFoundException: agoraSdkCWrapper with Agora in Unity on macOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

My Unity project with the Agora Video SDK has suddenly stopped working on macOS with an exception `DllNotFoundException: agoraSdkCWrapper`:

```
DllNotFoundException: agoraSdkCWrapper
agora_gaming_rtc.IRtcEngine.InitEngineCallback () (at Assets/AgoraEngine/Scripts/AgoraGamingSDK/AgoraGamingRtcEngine.cs:5820)
agora_gaming_rtc.IRtcEngine..ctor (System.String appId) (at Assets/AgoraEngine/Scripts/AgoraGamingSDK/AgoraGamingRtcEngine.cs:212)
agora_gaming_rtc.IRtcEngine.GetEngine (System.String appId) (at Assets/AgoraEngine/Scripts/AgoraGamingSDK/AgoraGamingRtcEngine.cs:4025)
```

The error seems to be system-related. It occurs in all projects on my system.

I have restarted the computer, cloned projects fresh, installed a different version of Unity, double-checked that agoraSdkCWrapper.bundle is included in the Editor and standalone and that the CPU is set for Intel 64-bit (setting it for Any CPU did not help either).

Agora works fine in builds made before the problem appeared.

A minimal reproduce is: create a new Unity project with the "3D" template, add Agora Video SDK for Unity from the Asset store, run the demo scene and click join.

MacOs 11.6 on a 2019 16-inch Macbook Pro with Intel, Unity 2020.3.11f1 and Unity 2020.3.21f1, Agora 3.4 and 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here:
For my current projects and newly created project that import latest sdk from unity asset store (v. 3.5.0.70 - released on October 21, 2021) but these errors still appear no matter what efforts to re-import the library:

DllNotFoundException: agoraSdkCWrapper
agora_gaming_rtc.IRtcEngine.InitEngineCallback () (at Assets/AgoraEngine/Scripts/AgoraGamingSDK/AgoraGamingRtcEngine.cs:5820)
agora_gaming_rtc.IRtcEngine..ctor (System.String appId) (at Assets/AgoraEngine/Scripts/AgoraGamingSDK/AgoraGamingRtcEngine.cs:212)
agora_gaming_rtc.IRtcEngine.GetEngine (System.String appId) (at Assets/AgoraEngine/Scripts/AgoraGamingSDK/AgoraGamingRtcEngine.cs:4025)

Note: It seems to Mac OS see this plugin as a malware so the file agoraCSdkWrapper.bundle cannot be open!

[Security Notice on Mac when re-import the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFr8W.png)

Mac BigSur 11.6, MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2018, Unity 2020.3.14f1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried on a different computer, macOS 10.15.7 Catalina. There at the moment when the library would be loaded a warning popped up: “agoraSdkCWrapper.bundle” will damage your computer. You should move it to the Bin. This file was downloaded on an unknown date.

Comment: From my experiences for this kind of issue: Delete old agoraSdkCWrapper.bundle from Unity Project, Re-download the plugin from agora website, unzip files, copy the agoraSdkCWrapper.bundle to MacOS folder in plugin (using MacOS finder, not open Unity Editor), then re-open unity editor. After re-import scripts from new lib files, Unity will log out some warning, its ok, press Run and this error will not appear. Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

this is Rick from Agora Developer Relations. Actually we had a Mac signing certificate issue back in the time for your download. Apologies to not being able to reach everyone that is affected. It should have been fixed on the Asset Store now (modified day Oct 27th) .  It was being discussed in [this thread in our Slack community](https://agoraiodev.slack.com/archives/CFDG7Q6F6/p1635284311053400) in case you want to look back.

Comment: This resolved the issue, thank you!

Comment: Hi Rick thanks for your reply. I use Mac M1. The Agora voice sdk worked fine in Unity Editor but had the same error after I built and ran the project for macOS. I followed your suggestion and downloaded the latest sdk from Asset Store (version 3.5.0.70, modified date Oct 28, 2021). However, the error persisted. I also tried downloading the video sdk folder from Agora website and dragged agoraSdkCWrapper.bundle to the macOS folder in the plugin folder inside AgoraEngine, but this way the system suggests that it could be a malware. I am wondering what I can do solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Xi, sorry to getting back to you late.  That's a common error happening on Unity Editor 2020.3 and up.  Please make sure you choose platform setting on the plugin according to you CPU.  The recommendation is use AnyCPU if your build setting is Intel+Apple.

Comment: Xi - if you are wondering, this screenshot shows you where to find this setting:
 https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1261195/144912564-7e125242-d7a9-473f-99c2-f3358345cc4d.png

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a DllNotFoundException error while working on an Agora Chat project in Unity on a Mac with an M2 chip. The error message was as follows:

DllNotFoundException: ChatCWrapper assembly: type: member:(null)
AgoraChat.NativeListener.AddNaitveListener () (at Assets/AgoraChat/AgoraChat/Native/NativeListener.cs:135)
AgoraChat.IClient..ctor (AgoraChat.NativeListener listener) (at Assets/AgoraChat/AgoraChat/Impls/IClient.cs:30)
AgoraChat.SDKClient..ctor () (at Assets/AgoraChat/AgoraChat/SDKClient.cs:24)
AgoraChat.SDKClient.get_Instance () (at Assets/AgoraChat/AgoraChat/SDKClient.cs:17)
NewBehaviourScript.setupChatSDK () (at Assets/AgoraChat/Scripts/NewBehaviourScript.cs:132)
NewBehaviourScript.Start () (at Assets/AgoraChat/Scripts/NewBehaviourScript.cs:224)

I found a solution to this issue by installing the Intel version of Unity, even though I was using a Mac with an M2 chip. Here are the steps I followed to resolve the problem:

1. Initially, I tried using the 2019.4.28 Intel version of Unity, which was already installed on my system. When I built the project with this version, it worked successfully.
2. After confirming that the 2019.4.28 Intel version resolved the issue, I decided to install the 2021.3.13 Intel version of Unity.
3. I rebuilt the Agora Chat project using the 2021.3.13 Intel version of Unity, and it continued to work without any DllNotFoundException errors.

In summary, the solution to the problem was to install and use the Intel version of Unity, regardless of whether you have a Mac with an M1 or M2 chip. This approach resolved the DllNotFoundException issue and allowed me to work on the project without further complications.